# Add Javascript functionality to more than one element

Tags: javascript, html, controls

I have a few lines of Javascript that define a custom 'play' button for HTML5 video.

The issue I have is that they work fine for one video, and for one video only. I want to have several videos on my page with the same Javascipt code affecting all of them. So that the play button works individually on each video. At the moment it only works on the first video listed in HTML.

How do I make this work?

JS

```
var vid, playbtn;

function intializePLayer(){
    vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause,false);
}

window.onload = intializePLayer;

function playPause(){
    if(vid.paused){
            vid.play();
            playbtn.style.opacity = '0';
    }else{
            vid.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url('http://i61.tinypic.com/xm8qdu.png')";
            playbtn.style.backgroundSize = "105px 105px";
            playbtn.style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#video_container{
    position:relative;
    width:480px;
    height:264px;
}

button#playpausebtn{
    background:url('http://i61.tinypic.com/xm8qdu.png') no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin:auto;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    width:105px;
    height:105px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size: 105px 105px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Video #1 -->
<div id="video_container">
    <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
    <video id="my_video" width="480" loop>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<!-- Video #2 -->
<div id="video_container">
    <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
    <video id="my_video" width="480" loop>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: ids must be unique. Use a class and get elements by class instead of id

Comment: IDs should be unique, use classes, as what Popnoodles said.

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this using .class? It seems like an excessive amount of code if I have say 10 videos on the same page and each one needs a unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will help you have one->n videos. In the fiddle we first search the DOM for elements with a class name of playpausebtn, then add an onclick listener for each. This listener takes the video object (which has to be directly after the button in this case, you could change this code to use an incrementing id e.g. video_1, video_2 etc and find the video objects that way) and adds it to the onclick event listener.

This is only one approach, but it is a way to resolve your issues - please ask questions if there is anything you don't understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/tL5ZU/1/

HTML:

```
<!-- Video #1 -->
<div>
    <button class="playpausebtn">Play</button>
    <video width="480" loop>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
<!-- Video #2 -->
<div>
    <button class="playpausebtn">Play</button>
    <video width="480" loop>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

JS

```
//set up listeners for buttons
function init() {
    //get all buttons
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('playpausebtn');
    //for each button set up the onclick listener
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = (function () {
            //the video needs to be right after the button
            var video = buttons[i].nextSibling.nextSibling;
            return function () {
                if (video.paused) {
                    video.play();
                } else {
                    video.pause();
                }
            };
        })();
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: That has solved the play button issue indeed! I am trying to implement the other buttons I had across the players but with no luck. I have actions for closing player, minimizing player, fullscreen and time update. See example here http://jsfiddle.net/tL5ZU/6/ Completely stuck

Comment: First, if this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. Next, I'm trying to figure out how to explain what is going on, rather than code it for you. The number one issue in your code is that each method you added relies on variables outside of the method instead of arguments being passed into the method (which makes each method independent). The second is that getElementsByClassName is returning you an array of DOM objects, not a single object - so you have to loop through them and work with the individual instance instead of the array.

Comment: Since you have multiple buttons, I would probably refactor your HTML to give each wrapping DIV a specific class, then find those and work with the buttons within them (rather than one loop for each button).